# How do we install Rubygems from Github under RVM?

Tags: rubygems, rvm

I'd like to use the latest RubyGems off of GitHub to fix the invalid gemspec time bug in the current Rubygems 1.8.10. The latter version is what you get when using `rvm` and saying `rvm rubygems current`, or `rvm rubygems latest`.

How can I teach `rvm` to install the head of the master branch of rubygems on github, or, how should I build that head locally to enable rvm to install it; or install it into RVM so it knows about it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update to the latest commit by running

```
oe1320:rubygems augusto$ gem -v
1.8.8

oe1320:ruby augusto$ git clone https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems.git
Cloning into rubygems...
remote: Counting objects: 22915, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6405/6405), done.
remote: Total 22915 (delta 16488), reused 22305 (delta 15937)
Receiving objects: 100% (22915/22915), 3.53 MiB | 676 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (16488/16488), done.

oe1320:ruby augusto$ cd rubygems/

oe1320:rubygems augusto$ git log -1
commit 57c969dac7e9e989ee9078d0803d0e2614c15761
Author: Eric Hodel <drbrain@segment7.net>
Date:   Thu Sep 15 12:13:12 2011 -0700

Add jruby and rubinius to travis-ci

oe1320:rubygems augusto$ ruby setup.rb 
RubyGems 1.8.10 installed
[...]

oe1320:rubygems augusto$ cd
oe1320:~ augusto$ gem -v
1.8.10
```

As you can see I just updated from gem 1.8.8 to the [latest commit from 1.8.10](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/commit/57c969dac7e9e989ee9078d0803d0e2614c15761)

### EDIT

As I mentioned on the comment, I'm also running under RVM. When you run `ruby setup.rb` inside the rubygems forlder, it installs the `gem` script and sources in the correct folder. You don't need to do anything special.

```
$ gem which rubygems
/home/augusto/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb

$ rvm -v

rvm 1.6.32 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

Comment: I'm under rvm, will that make rvm recognize the recent-most version so it works properly with rvm?

Comment: I'm also running everything with rvm. Please see the update so you can see which version of RVM I'm using